# Can i use Rails to make a phongap app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova, ruby-on-rails-4, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Can i make a website using rails (database backed ofcourse) and use phonegap to make a native app vertin of it ?
I know that phone gap is agnostic of back-end technologies but i didn't find any answer for my question.

Comment: You can also use  jQuery functionality to do it,you will only need to fire the ajax function and ajax external file coding can be present in rail or any other environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Phonegap consist only in HTML, CSS and Javascript. You can build up your web service either REST or SOAP API using Rails.

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/07/15/simple-hybrid-mobile-app-using-cordova-and-ratchet-2-complete/